# Is this short proof of Taylor's theorem correct?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> Let $g:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{k+1}$ function, $a,x \in I$, then: $$g(x)=g(a)+g'(a)(x-a)+ \ldots +\frac{1}{k!}g^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k+ \quad \frac{1}{k!}\int_a^x(x-s)^kg^{(k+1)}(s)\,ds $$
>   **Proof:** Taking $x$ fixed, the RHS of the equation above is a function of $a$ and its derivative wrt $a$ is zero (that can be easily verified, so I will not write the computations, for the last term simply use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus), so it remains constant when varying $a$. In particular when it is evaluated at $a=x$ its value is $g(x)$ as wanted.
>   Since the function is constant (when varying $a$) then the RHS equals $g(x)$ for all $a \in I$ and since $x$ was arbitrary the equation holds for all $x \in I$

Can anyone confirm this proof is correct? It seems tricky and so simple that makes me suspect

BTW this is taken from the apendix of Hubbard's book *Vector calculus, linear algebra and differential forms*

Comment: @mixedmath I don't understand why it would require $k+2$ differentiability of $g$. I also don't realize of the problem with $h$. I mean, I could have stated the theorem without any mention to $h$, using only $x$ as variable. I will edit, to make it clearer

Comment: @chilangoincomprendido why is that I can't conclude the derivative wrt $a$  of the RHS is zero, $h$ is not in the equation anymore after the change of variable

Comment: Yes, I see what you did now. Looks fine. You verified the formula. But of course, verifying a formula without seeing "where it comes from" is not very instructive. Anyway, I will delete my previous comments.

Comment: No, it's fine. I agree it's not very instructive, it is completly artificial and the procedure seems kind of tricky, but on the other hand it's very simple. BTW I still don't "trust" in that proof, that's why I'm asking for a confirmation of correctness

Comment: Your proof is correct. But notice that using integrals you need the continuity of $f^{(n+1)}$. The more general theorem holds with just existence of $f^{(n+1)}$ and it avoids integrals.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh actually no. The general case (which I know) assumes $f^n$ is absolutely continuous. The  rhs is obviously AC in $a$. Now, the derivative is $0$ almost everywhere. A AC function on an interval is constant iff its derivative is $0$ almost everywhere. So referring to the right version of FTC the proof still works in the general case.

Comment: @user251257: You are referring to the case when the integral in question is Lebesgue integral, right?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes